# Comparing convex planar regions of equal perimeter and area - 2

Tags: discrete-geometry, convex-geometry, computational-geometry

We try to extend [On comparing planar convex regions of equal perimeter and area](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/357124/on-comparing-planar-convex-regions-of-equal-perimeter-and-area) .

Given two planar convex regions C1 and C2 both with unit perimeter, we define the *difference* between C1 and C2 as the least value of Hausdorff distance between C1 and C2 can have when the regions are placed above one another and transformed with isometries (rotation, translation, reflection) to minimise the Hausdorff distance between them.

**Question:** Given a planar convex region C, to find that convex region C' with same area A and perimeter p as C such that difference(C, C') is maximized.

Consider the related question of finding the *pair of regions* C1 and C2 with area A and perimeter p such that difference(C1, C2) is maximized. Then, one can ask if for any C, C' is necessarily one of either C1 or C2.

**Variant:** One can ask about more quantities than {area, perimeter} to be equal among the regions.

**A special case:** Which planar convex region is at maximum difference from a square and with same area and perimeter as  the square?

**Note:** One can also consider other measures of difference between convex regions Ci and Cj than the Hausdorff distance - for example, the average least distance of a boundary point on Cj from a boundary point on Ci or the area/perimeter of the intersection of Ci and Cj (an earlier post on this last idea is [Optimal intersections between planar convex regions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/413124/optimal-intersections-between-planar-convex-regions) )

Comment: Have you calculated any examples of this difference? If not, I would say this is more in the realm of speculation than research.

Comment: One could visualize a clearly defined continuum of *triangles* all of same area and perimeter starting with an isosceles triangle of narrow base and ending with another isosceles triangle with wide base. But I am not sure if the two 'end triangles' are indeed the most distant pair. Reg square (the special case mentioned in question), I don't know how to begin.